# Place text box in appbar in Flutter

Tags: search, flutter, appbar

I want to implement an Appbar like below where there are a textbox and multiple icons:

[image: appbar layout]

The icons can be added in action easily, but how to add the text box and add search action to it. There are many search bar plugins available, but all of them occupy the whole app bar and no way to mention the hints. Can anyone give some idea, it will be a great help for me.

Comment: add what you done till now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the title propiery, inside the AppBar, you can pass a widget, which means you can add any component you want, like a TextField. see the example below:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I suggest to you, to wrap this TextField in a GestureDetector, disable the TextField with the proprierty called `enable` (set to false), and in the `onTap` method inside the GestureDetector, you can call a `showSearch()` method.

To call this `showSearch()`, you'll need to pass a `context` and a `searchDelegate` which is a component that extends a class, check this example:

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
    return null;
  }
}
```

Source: [Implementing search in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutterpub/implementing-search-in-flutter-17dc5aa72018)

Now, you can do this:

```
GestureDetector:
  onTap: () => showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchScreen()),
  child: ....
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a great help.

Comment: The Idea of converting text field into the Search bar wtih Search delegate fun. is a great idea. Thanks